# QListView & QStandardItemModel check text before editing row

Tags: c++, qt, events, qlistview, qstandarditemmodel

I want to check the text of a row in `QListView` before the user is editing it. If it doesn't fit a pattern, I don't want to accept it.

Currently I have a `QListView` and `QStandardItemModel`. I can easily add and remove items via the `QStandardItemModel`. I also set the model of the list view.

Are there some `delegates` or `event` function(s) on the list or the model for editing?

Comment: why you cannot do it in setData() ?

Comment: did you overload setData() and data() functions for your model?

Comment: No I didn't overload them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can overload `data()` and `setData()` functions from `QStandardItemModel`, then when user tries to edit item your `setData` will be called with `Qt::EditRole` and there you can do your processing.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qabstractitemmodel.html#setData

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to override `appendRow`?

Comment: QStandardItemModel has appendRow function, it is not virtual, see a class reference http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qstandarditemmodel.html

Comment: you don't need to override it, this is why this is called StandardItemModel, it just defines this method some way and you agreed for this implementation - this is why you have chosen StandardModel. If you need custom behaviour of appendRow you should inherit from QAbstractItemModel, there appendRow is virtual & you can override it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to check the value of an item at the time the user attempts to enter the edit mode?

Using a delegate should work for this fairly well:

```
class MyItemDelegate : public QItemDelegate {
    public:
        QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const {
            if(index.data() == /* do whatever check you want here */) {
                return NULL; // Prevent editing
            }
            return QItemDelegate::createEditor(parent, option, index);
        }
};

listView->setItemDelegate(new MyItemDelegate());
```

Comment: `qDebug() << index.data().toString();` gives me `QVariant(QString, "asdfdsaf")` but not the real string `asdfdsaf`. How can I get the raw data.

Comment: QString s = index.data().toString();