# Value before change?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtablewidget

I have a model `QStandardItemModel` and subscribe to `itemChanged()` signal, where I get the changed item.

Is there any way how to get value of changed item before this change?

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL("itemChanged(QStandardItem *)"), self.sModelChanged)
```

Comment: Sorry, What class your implement ? Is it `QStandardItemModel` ?

Comment: yes, sorry I should mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470445/qlistview-qstandarditemmodel-check-text-before-editing-row) in past. (Qt, C++)

Before read my answer, I show how to implement in pyqt4. It's not my idea, But I will show how to do that.

---

The class [`QtGui.QStandardItemModel`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstandarditemmodel.html) have only `void itemChanged (QStandardItem*)`. So you have to create your custom signal itself.

1) For this case, I recommend to inheritance class `QtGui.QStandardItemModel` to create own class to implement get value of changed item before this change.

2) Next, override [`bool QStandardItemModel.setData (self, QModelIndex index, QVariant value, int role = Qt.EditRole)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstandarditemmodel.html#setData) should be fine to track data changed (But it can't track in contractor initiated).

3) And create signal your own before set data;

Implemented example (PyQt4, Python);

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class QNonStandardItemModel (QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    itemBeforeAndAfterChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QModelIndex, int, QtCore.QVariant, QtCore.QVariant)
    def setData (self, indexQModelIndex, afterValueQVariant, role = QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        beforeValueQVariant = self.data(indexQModelIndex, role)
        self.itemBeforeAndAfterChanged.emit(indexQModelIndex, role, beforeValueQVariant, afterValueQVariant)
        return QtGui.QStandardItemModel.setData(self, indexQModelIndex, afterValueQVariant, role)

myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication([])
myQTreeView = QtGui.QTreeView()

headerQStandardItemModel = QNonStandardItemModel()
def callback (indexQModelIndex, role, beforeValueQVariant, afterValueQVariant):
    print '#' * 80
    print 'Before:', beforeValueQVariant.toString()
    print 'After:', afterValueQVariant.toString()
    print 'Role:', role

headerQStandardItemModel.itemBeforeAndAfterChanged.connect(callback)
headerQStandardItemModel.setHorizontalHeaderLabels([''] * 4)
myQTreeView.setModel(headerQStandardItemModel)
row1QStandardItem = QtGui.QStandardItem('ROW 1')
row1QStandardItem.appendRow([QtGui.QStandardItem(''), QtGui.QStandardItem('COLUMN 1'), QtGui.QStandardItem('COLUMN 2'), QtGui.QStandardItem('COLUMN 3')])
headerQStandardItemModel.appendRow(row1QStandardItem)

myQTreeView.show()
sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

Comment: return super(QtGui.QStandardItemModel, self).setData(indexQModelIndex, afterValueQVariant, role)
is not working how as expected, I replace this line with
return QtGui.QStandardItemModel.setData(self, indexQModelIndex, afterValueQVariant, role)

Comment: Oh! It's my fault. Thanks. I fixed it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no a standard way to get notified when `QStandardItem` is changed. However, you can easily implement it:

- Create a new class inherited from `QStandardItem`.
- Reimplement `clone` to create this class objects from the model.
- Reimplement `setData` method and notify the item is changed. See below two ways how to do that.
- Set new class as prototype to the model (`setItemPrototype`).

There are two ways to go further:

1. Inherit you item class from `QObject` also to emit a signal from `setData` and subscribe to each item somewhere (I wouldn't do that).
2. Add signal `itemAboutToChange` to `QStandardItemModel`.

I expand on #2:

- Create a new class inherited from `QStandardItemModel`.
- Add macro `Q_OBJECT` and new signal `itemAboutToChange(QStandardItem*)`
- In `setData` of a class derived from `QStandardItem` call the signal from the model.

Here is how to call the signal:

```
 QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self.model(), "itemAboutToChange", Qt::DirectConnection, Q_ARG(QStandardItem*, self));
```